# Fuse - how to create custom fuse commands

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

In fuse we can add profiles to the container by using command fabric:container-add-profile.When we have deployed an application,how can we define application specific commands , for example : command to export application properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuse is based on Karaf. The karaf documentation will show you how to create commands: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/extending.html

Note: Don't forget to target the same version of Karaf as Fuse is using.

Good luck!